# Kinetic model of proton reduction

Tags: redox, kinetics

One of my colleagues is working on a homogeneous catalyst ($\ce{X}$) for proton reduction. The simplified proposed mechanism for it is the following.

$$\ce{X + 2 e^- ->[$k_1$] X^{2-}}    \tag{1}$$

$$\ce{X^{2-} + H+ <=>[$k_2$,\,slow][$k_{-2}$] XH-}    \tag{2}$$

$$\ce{XH- + H+ <=>[$k_3$][$k_{-3}$] X + H2}   \tag{3}$$

However, this is not a true catalyst and it degrades over time:

$$\ce{X ->[$k_\text{inact}$] X_\text{inact}}$$

We monitor $\ce{H2}$ at different time intervals and we plot the turnover number (TON), defined as the total number of moles of $\ce{H2}$ produced per mole of initial catalyst (so if we produce 20 mmol of $\ce{H2}$ in an experiment where we started with 2 mmol of catalyst, the TON at that time is 10).

Is there a way to derive an equation for the TON vs time plot that only depends on total $\ce{H2}$ and time? (We get something that looks hyperbolic, like Michaelis Menten plots, but we don't know if it's hyperbolic, exponential, or something else).

---

**My attempt:**

Assuming steady-state of the intermediate, $\ce{XH-}$ (and I'm not sure we should!):

$k_2[\ce{X^{2-}}][\ce{H+}] + k_{-3}[\ce{X}][\ce{H2}]= k_{-2}[\ce{XH-}][\ce{H+}] + k_{3}[\ce{XH-}][\ce{H+}] $

$\displaystyle [\ce{XH-}] = \frac{k_2[\ce{X^{2-}}][\ce{H+}] + k_{-3}[\ce{X}][\ce{H2}]}{(k_{-2}+k_3)[\ce{H+}]}$

The rate law is given by:

$\displaystyle \frac{d[\ce{H2}]}{dt} = k_3[\ce{XH-}][\ce{H+}] - k_{-3}[\ce{X}][\ce{H2}]$

So:

$\displaystyle \frac{d[\ce{H2}]}{dt} = k_3\left(\frac{k_2[\ce{X^{2-}}][\ce{H+}] + k_{-3}[\ce{X}][\ce{H2}]}{(k_{-2}+k_3)}\right) - k_{-3}[\ce{X}][\ce{H2}]$

From here I am not sure how to proceed. I think it is safe to assume that $[\ce{X}]$ is constant in the catalytic cycle so we can say that $[\ce{X}] = [\ce{X}]_0 e^{-k_\text{inact}t}$. However, I'm not sure how to treat $[\ce{X^{2-}}]$, and I'm not exactly sure how to solve the integral for $[\ce{H2}]$ from there. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your equation ($ii$) is neither mass nor charge balanced.  Would you please correct that first.

Comment: Oops, I had it all in sequence and later decided to show it in steps for clarity and missed that. It is edited now.

Comment: @ralk I would recommend maybe change your "C" for catalyst to something else. Some of the steps could be mistaken for unusual carbon compounds.

Comment: Well maybe it is carbon :P

Comment: About TON vs time plot, did you try to graph on excel? You may able to check whether it is hyperbolic or exponential easily.

Comment: We've actually done the fit for a generic hyperbolic or exponential equation and it fits pretty well for both. That's why we are trying to come up with a model that supports one or the other. (The other problem being we have no idea what the $k$ values are!).

Comment: If you're not sure if a species should be a fleeting intermediate for the purposes of steady state analysis, you should draw a reaction coordinate diagram for a single cycle.

Comment: Do you have any mechanistic prediction for how the catalyst inactivates? Specifically, which species is involved? For example, it might be more accurate to write your inactivation step as $k_{inact}[X^{2-}]$. That difference could be important in getting a good model for TON.  More generally, I would take the approach of writing the rate laws as diff. eqs and fitting by simulation rather than making SS assumptions (that might not be valid) and trying to solve explicitly. Many computer programs are available to do this.

Comment: You definitely make several good points, I think you might be correct by saying it's more likely to be $k_{inact}[\ce{X^{2-}}]$. I guess the best choice is to do as you say since it will probably require many other assumptions to get an explicit solution.